# TLA hell and Lenovo T450s trackpad/keyboard bezel replacement parts

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

I intend to replace the buggy and unergonomic trackpad on my T440s with a T450s' trackpad as i believe they are compatible.

This link is to a bill of materials for a T450s from Lenovo's website:
https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/t450_frubom_20150127.pdf

From the bezels section on page 3, I believe I need to choose from one of these:

```
00HN549 N FRU KBD Bezel ASM UMA w/FPR,w/dock
00HN550 N FRU KBD Bezel ASM UMA w/o FPR,,w/dock
00HN551 N FRU KBD Bezel ASM UMA w/oFPR w/oNFC,no dock
00HN552 N FRU KBD Bezel ASM SWG w/oFPR,no dock
```

I'm confident in these translations:

- FRU = Field Replacement Unit
- FPR = Finger print reader
- NFC = Near Field Commnunication

and `KBD Bezel ASM` is surely `keyboard bezel assembly`

`FRU 00HN551`'s description contains `w/oNFC`, but none of the other descriptions mention NFC.

`FRU 00HN550`'s description contains `w/o FPR,,w/dock` [sic]. Perhaps this line should have contained `w/NFC`?

When considering a keyboard bezel assembly, I cannot produce a guess for `w/dock` vs `no dock`.

Nor for UMA vs SWG,  perhaps they are something to do with the trackpad?

Comment: I agree on Finger Print Reader, FRU, KBD.. NFC and dock is a mystery, UMA/SWG is usually a reference to graphics.